# Getting average per line

Tags: awk, average

I have a large data set in this format

```
HF TLLL A T 0.999 NA 0.666 NA 0.566 NA NA 0.87
HF TLLM A T 0.500 0.500 0.666 0.566 NA NA 0.87
```

I want to calculate an average for each line, starting from column 5 until end of line, and ignoring the string `NA`. Then append the average to the end of each line.

The output would look like this:

```
HF TLLL A T 0.999 NA 0.666 NA 0.566 NA NA 0.87 0.775
HF TLLM A T 0.500 0.500 0.666 0.566 NA NA 0.87 0.620
```

I have been getting the sum like this, but can't figure out how to keep track of the number of integers that were summed, in order to calculate the average.

```
awk '{x=0;for(i=5;i<=NF;i++)x=x+$i;print $0, x}'
```

Comment: I assume by [***average***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average), you mean ***arithmetic mean***.  Does "NA" count as a zero data point, or are they ignored completely?  This will affect the number of datapoints from each line, and thus the computed mean.

Comment: Yes, I mean arithmetic mean. The NA should be ignored completely.

Comment: I wonder why you got down-voted on this question. You have sample input, expected out, an explanation for the mapping, and an attempted solution. It's just about the perfect question as far as I can tell!

Comment: Someone made a down vote for this post.  It would be nice to know why.  Post is nicely written, input data, expected output, and a try to solve it. So I up voted. Edit: @EdMorton you beat me by some sec :)

Comment: @Jotne good idea on the upvote, I've done likewise now.

Comment: Agreed.  The question is a good one, and I'm upvoting too.  (though it did need a little bit of clarification as per my comment).  The downvote was not mine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ cat file
HF TLLL A T 0.999 NA 0.666 NA 0.566 NA NA 0.87
HF TLLM A T 0.500 0.500 0.666 0.566 NA NA 0.87
HF TLLM A T NA NA NA NA NA NA NA

$ awk '{sum=cnt=0; for (i=5;i<=NF;i++) if ($i != "NA") { sum+=$i; cnt++ } print $0, (cnt ? sum/cnt : "NA") }' file
HF TLLL A T 0.999 NA 0.666 NA 0.566 NA NA 0.87 0.77525
HF TLLM A T 0.500 0.500 0.666 0.566 NA NA 0.87 0.6204
HF TLLM A T NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

The ternary expression avoids a divide by zero error on input row 3 where every data field is "NA".

Comment: +1 for the `0/0` check. I thought of this when I wrote `s=n=0` but forgot when `printf` ...

Answer (score 1):

```
kent$  awk '{s=n=0;for(i=5;i<=NF;i++)if($i!="NA"){s+=$i*1;n++}printf "%s %.3f\n",$0,s/n}' file
HF TLLL A T 0.999 NA 0.666 NA 0.566 NA NA 0.87 0.775
HF TLLM A T 0.500 0.500 0.666 0.566 NA NA 0.87 0.620
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`, you can do this:

```
awk '{for (i=5;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i!="NA") t++;a+=$i}print $0,a/t;a=t=0}' file
HF TLLL A T 0.999 NA 0.666 NA 0.566 NA NA 0.87 0.77525
HF TLLM A T 0.500 0.500 0.666 0.566 NA NA 0.87 0.6204
```