# How can I use unix to calculate average of columns?

Tags: linux, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
length_1    10   5   7 
length_2     8   3   2 
length_3     3   2   1 
..
length_999   1   5   4
```

I want the average (mean) of the 3 columns to be calculated:

```
length_1    7.3333
length_2    4.3333 
length_3    2
..
length_999  2.6666
```

Is there an easy way to do this in linux?

Comment: This is very similar: [Getting average per line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19984012/getting-average-per-line)

Comment: note that your last average is wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `awk`:

```
awk '{print $1" "($2+$3+$4)/3}' file
```

Answer (score 3):

more generally, for arbitrary number of columns

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NF>1 {s=0; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) s+=$i; 
                         print $1, s/(NF-1)}' file

length_1        7.33333
length_2        4.33333
length_3        2
length_999      3.33333
```